# Hodge-star operator and wedge product on Lie algebra valued forms

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a an oriented riemannian manifold.
I have seen the following definition for the Hodge-star operator acting on a differential form. Starting with $\beta\in \Omega^p(M)$ we have
$$\alpha \wedge \star \beta = \left<\alpha,\beta\right>\text{vol} ~~\forall \alpha \in \Omega^p(M)$$

where $ \left<\alpha,\beta\right> = \left<e^1\wedge\ldots\wedge e^p, f^1\wedge \ldots \wedge f^p\right> = \det[\left<e^i,f^j\right>]$.

My question is if we have a Lie algebra (of a matrix group) valued form $F\in \Omega^p(M,g)$. How do we now define the Hodge star operator ?. I am asking this question because I want to understand expressions such as
$$ F \wedge \star F$$
in the context of Yang-Mills theory.
Thank you very much.

EDIT:
I think my confusion really comes from the fact wheter I should use the commutator or the matrix product as the first answer kindly mentioned.
In the case of Yang-Mills functional is it meant as: $$
L_{YM}= \int_{M}Tr(F\wedge\star F), ~~F = \sum\limits_{j}\omega_j \otimes g_j\in \Omega^2(M,g) \\Tr(F\wedge \star F) = \sum\limits_{j,k}\left<\omega_j, \omega_k\right>\text{vol}~\text{Tr}([g_j,g_k])$$
or is it meant as
$$F\in \Omega^2(M,g) \\Tr(F\wedge \star F) = \sum\limits_{j,k}\left<\omega_j, \omega_k\right>\text{vol}~\text{Tr}(g_jg_k).$$
Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hodge star is not any different. But, depending on the notation you're using, if you have Lie-algebra valued forms, you use wedge on the forms and Lie bracket on the Lie-algebra part. To be explicit, if you have
$F= \sum\limits_j \omega_j\otimes v_j$ and $G = \sum\limits_k\eta_k\otimes w_k$, with $\omega_j,\eta_k$ differential forms and $v_j,w_k\in\mathfrak g$, then
$F\wedge G = \sum\limits_{j,k} (\omega_j\wedge\eta_k) \otimes [v_j,w_k]$.

Some authors will use regular matrix product rather than matrix commutator, when working with matrix-valued forms, so you need to check your particular author.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a small question at the end of my original post.

Comment: Well, trace of a commutator is $0$ :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misteaking, the first expression you propose vanishes as the trace is conjugaison invariant. Moreover YM action is not suppose to measure only an error of commutation (with G=U(1), YM should be different from 0).